# Вывод/передача String на экране Android

Tags: java, android, консоль

Добрый день. Я начинаю осваивать Android Api и хочу вывести строку на экране телефона через консоль ПК, связанные через USB. К сожалению поиски в сети не увенчались успехом и надеюсь, что мне смогут помочь тут. Спасибо.

Comment: а как у вас связаны пк и телефон?

Comment: ПК и телефон связаны через USB

Comment: Ну тогда план примерно такой: из java добраться до USB-портов найти нужный, подключиться к нему и кидать запросы андроиду, правда как это сделать и зачем я не знаю =) Вы лучше расскажите с какой целью вам это надо, может вы делаете не то что нужно

Comment: Я это делаю, потому что мой товарищ не верит, что это возможно = ) 
А конечная цель: телефон должен звонить и отправлять сообщения при срабатывания соответствующего триггера. А кроме как передать сообщение через консоль, ничего лучше не придумал.

Comment: Как вариант, поставьте приложение Termux и в добавку Termux API. Так вы сможете показывать сообщения, слать уведомления, отправлять сообщения, USSD запросы, получать местонахождение, делать скрытое фото камеры, делать скриншоты. Ещё более широкие возможности приходят с Рут правами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете соединить ПК и Android через ADB. Как включить/настроить/установить его - найдите в интернете. Напрямую, через ADB можно вызвать broadcast receiver. Допустим ваш пекейж **com.myapp.app** (замените на свой)

Итак, берём и создаём ресивер (допустим в корне пекейжа)

```
public class ConsoleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

И теперь обьявим его в манифесте

```
<receiver android:name=".ConsoleReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="com.myapp.app.intent.TEST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Имя интента (TEST на конце) используем для команды

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.myapp.app.intent.TEST -n com.myapp.app.ConsoleReceiver --es msg "Hello, world!"
```

Эту команду пишем на консоли ADB на ПК и видим тост на экране смартфона

Я написал все что выше без IDE, с телефона, могут быть ошибки, по поводу того, чтобы показывать текст не в тосте, а, на экране приложения, погуглите, как связать бродкаст и активити, если что завтра выложу код с утра.

Кстати, используя ADB вы можете отсоединить USB и держать соединение с помощью Wifi/Bluetooth, тоже на эту тему советую погуглить

**Вариант 2**

Ну это так, для ленивых. Ставим Termux + Termux API из Google Play. Включаем ADB на обоих сторонах и пишем

```
termux-toast -s "Hacked!1!!1!111!"
```

Все команды Termux здесы: [тык](https://termux.com/add-on-api.html)

Кстати, можете поковырять исходный код Termux API чтобы окончательно разобраться с Receiver. Загрузитк его APK [сюда](http://javadecompilers.com/apk), потом скачайте исходный код и изучите (там не так много кода)

Comment: К сожалению, не получается вывести тост на экран. Команда в консоле выдает нечто подобное:
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.example pkg=firstapp.intent.TEST }
Broadcast completed: result=0
Я пробовал запускать с разными аргументами и извлекая все устройства из ноутбука, но результат тот же.

Comment: У меня в ответе там пробел между `com.myapp` и `app`... Извините, исправил, напишите команду без него

Comment: В вашем случае `adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.firstapp.intent.TEST --es msg "Hello world"`

Comment: С пробелом не возникло проблем = ) 
Но даже с исправленным скриптом, не работает. Меня смущает ключ "-а".В документации написано, что это для сетевых устройств, а телефон подключен по USB.

Comment: Ключ a означать action, который прописан в ресивере в манифесте) и все-таки вы в тот раз ошиблись :) в первом вашем комментарии здесь вы написали что пишет adb. Там у вас разделилось act и pkg.

Comment: Но вообще я точно не знаю, попробуйте заменить тост на логи. `Log.d("broadcast", msg);` и ещё попробуйте в манифесте добавить к `android:enabled="true"` ещё и `android:exported="true"`

Comment: Ещё вопрос, вы перед отправкой команды запускаете приложение? Если нет, и вам нужен приём в фоне, то необходимо ещё написать сервис

Comment: Манифест менять пробовал. Вначале запускаю приложение, а затем отправляю через терминал команду. Не могу понять почему происходит разделение. 
>adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.firstapp.intent.TEST --es msg "Hello, world!"
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.example.firstapp.intent.TEST pkg=world! (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0

Comment: А!!! Надо указать ключ n передав в него путь до ресивера! Я обновил команду в ответе